# Showing label while program is loading

Tags: c#, winforms, label, loading

I have a form with a Log In field (username and password). When I log in my Form will load some SQL Databases and GridViews displaying the tables and columns. Depending on how large the data amount is, it will take a while till everything gets loaded and a "logged in" label appears (which is only visible when the user is logged in). Is there a possibility to display another label ("loading") between the event when I press the button and when the "logged in" label appears?

Comment: That depends how you've coded you data IO. The answer will be substantially different dependent on whether or not your loading that "take a while" runs synchronously or asynchronously.

Comment: How can I find that out?

Comment: By posting code with your question?

Comment: How much code? And what part of it. That's a huge amount... When I hit the button then he runs a couple of methods which read from a textfile, load everything into Textboxes, load databases into DataGridViews, fill Listboxes and so on. When everything worked fine then a "logged in" label appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put your loading data code in a background thread can do the job while the ui thread is showing loading
that's the idea

Comment: How to handle this? I want that the label disappears after the "logged in" label appears. I tried to put label.Visible = true right behind the button event and before he calls the class and methods but that doesn't work. Is there maybe an button event which fires before the button fires?

Comment: here is a complete example for doing alike [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

Comment: That's even better! Thank you!